# Cascading Combo Boxes with a date range filter

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

[image]

Im trying to figure out if there is a way to link a data range which is encompassed in two textboxes with the calender button to select a date and 3 other filtering combo boxes. I want the combo boxes to filter off of each other based on the date of the record. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks so much!

```
Private Sub cmbFleetID_AfterUpdate()
Me.cmbOwner.Requery
Me.cmbTailNumber.Requery
End Sub
Private Sub cmbOwner_AfterUpdate()
Me.cmbFleetID.Requery
Me.cmbTailNumber.Requery
End Sub
Private Sub cmbTailNumber_AfterUpdate()
Me.cmbFleetID.Requery
Me.cmbOwner.Requery
End Sub
```

This is the code I have so far. As you can see I have the combo boxes cascading off of each other with the code in the queries for each combo box as well [forms]![ReportNavigation]![cmbName]. I just cant figure out how to put the date range text boxes into it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Could you update your post with that?

Comment: [This](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html) example might get you started. And as @PaulFrancis stated, to receive help please add what you have done so far.

Comment: I have added what I have so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the user will enter a date range and the three comboboxes will automatically update/requery themselves based on the date range entered?

If so, in the `RowSource` field of the combobox, build your query to access these fields in the form like this:

`SELECT tblTestData.ID, tblTestData.ACName, tblTestData.ActiveDate FROM tblTestData WHERE (((tblTestData.ActiveDate) Between [Forms].[frmTest].[txtDateBegin] And [Forms].[frmTest].[txtDateEnd]));`

Clearly, you have to replace the `frmTest` with your form name and `txtDateBegin/End` with your textbox names. With this RowSource, each requery will appropriately pull the data from your table.

Comment: Thank you! Just one question, where you have tblTestData entries do I need all of those if the combobox values all come from the same table?

Comment: Im getting an error that says "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: My guess is that your query is too restrictive and can only find one record that matches. What I've done most often is create a new (temporary/test) query and build a SQL query, then look at the returns. You may have to add some temporary parameters (like begin and end dates). But you'll get a better idea of what the query will do before you attach it to the control in the RowSource.